# what language can be use in order to create a website that will soon be converted into mobile app?

Tags: php

I want to create a networking platform that will run both browser and mobile apk

is there any idea? I know that this is not related to code but i am searching for the answer for a while now please advise thank you very much

Comment: As you have said, it is not related to coding. Please note that it is also opinion-based, and your question can also be regarded as seeking recommendations (for books, tools, software libraries, and more) -- `what language can be use [used] ......`

Answer (score 0):

You could use Angular framework to develop your Web App and then convert it into an Ionic App which is a framework used to develop hybrid mobile apps.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest React. React has React Native which can be used to create progressive web apps which can operate as individual apps on phones, desktops or even in the web from the same code base from what I understand. But I am sure the learning curve can be a bit steep.